# XPath - Select first element of by analyzing following-siblings

Tags: xml, xpath

I have xml like follows,

```
<section>
        <p id="ss_main">aa</p>
        <p id="ss_main">bb</p>
        <p id="main">cc</p>
        <p id="main">dd</p>
        <p id="main">ee</p>
        <p id="ss_main">ff</p>
        <p id="main">gg</p>
        <p id="main">hh</p>
        <p id="main">ii</p>
        <p id="main">jj</p>
        <p id="ss_main">xx</p>
        <p id="ss_main">yy</p>
        <p id="ss_main">zz</p>
    </section>
```

you can see consecutive `<p>` elements which attributes is staring from `ss` . what I need is using xpath select the 1st `<p>` element of every group which attribute is starting from `ss` .

SO in above xml  `<p id="ss_main">aa</p>` , `<p id="ss_main">ff</p>` ,  `<p id="ss_main">xx</p>` should be selected.

I can write `p[starts-with(@id,'ss')]` which select all `<p>` element that id attr starting from `ss` and `p[starts-with(@id,'ss')][1]` which select only 1st `<p>` element that `id` starting from `ss` .

Can anyone suggest me a method how can I select first `<p>` element of each group that attr starting from `ss` ??

Comment: Is your XPath engine embedded in XSLT 2.0? or some other programming language? It makes a difference because if XSLT, you could leverage `xsl:for-each-group`.

Comment: Also, what version of XPath?

Comment: If element `<p id="ssA">A</p>` is immediately followed by element `<p id="ssB">B<p>`, are these two elements in one group? or two? In other words, does the `@id` value after the ss prefix affect the identification of groups?

Comment: @SeanB.Durkin , <p id="ssA">A</p> is immediately followed by element <p id="ssB">B<p>, those can be considered as same group.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

**This is one possible XPath :**

```
//p[starts-with(@id, 'ss')][not(preceding-sibling::p[1][starts-with(@id, 'ss')])]
```

**brief explanation :**

- `//p[starts-with(@id, 'ss')]` : find all `p` elments having `id` attribute starts with `"ss"`...
- `[not(preceding-sibling::p[1][starts-with(@id, 'ss')])]` : ... and not having direct preceding sibling element `p` with the `id` attribute starts with `"ss"`

Answer (score 1):

For this answer, I am assuming that you are using XPath 2.0 and that a different suffix (part of `@id` content after the ss prefix) starts a new group.

This XPath 2.0 expression ...

```
p[ starts-with( @id, 'ss')]
 [ not( @id eq preceding-sibling::p[1]/@id)]
```

... applied to document ...

```
<section>
  <p id="ss_main">aa</p>
  <p id="ss_main">bb</p>
  <p id="main">cc</p>
  <p id="main">dd</p>
  <p id="main">ee</p>
  <p id="ss_main">ff</p>
  <p id="main">gg</p>
  <p id="main">hh</p>
  <p id="main">ii</p>
  <p id="main">jj</p>
  <p id="ss_main">xx</p>
  <p id="ss_main">yy</p>
  <p id="ss_main">zz</p>
</section>
```

... where the focus node is the `section` element, resolves to ...

```
<p id="ss_main">aa</p>
<p id="ss_main">ff</p>
<p id="ss_main">xx</p>
```

Furthermore, when we apply the same expression to ...

```
<section>
  <p id="ss_main">aa</p>
  <p id="ss_DifferentGroup">bb</p>
  <p id="main">cc</p>
  <p id="main">dd</p>
  <p id="main">ee</p>
  <p id="ss_main">ff</p>
  <p id="main">gg</p>
  <p id="main">hh</p>
  <p id="main">ii</p>
  <p id="main">jj</p>
  <p id="ss_main">xx</p>
  <p id="ss_main">yy</p>
  <p id="ss_main">zz</p>
</section>
```

... with the same focus node, we get ...

```
<p id="ss_main">aa</p>
<p id="ss_DifferentGroup">bb</p>
<p id="ss_main">ff</p>
<p id="ss_main">xx</p>
```